# Colorwithpattern for coreimage color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, core-image, cgcolor

I am using CIAztecCodeGenerator to generate an Aztec code.

I'm trying to set a pattern instead of a solid color for the foreground color for it however it is rendering as blank/white I was wondering if anyone knew what I am doing wrong.

```
[colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image] CGColor]] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid Core Image doesn't support pattern colors, only RGBA values. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ahh thats annoying! i'm trying to allow a user selected image to be applied as a pattern for the aztec codes fore color. I presume there is no way around that. Is there any way I could use the aztec code as a mask which I could "clip" the user selected image to maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated, but you can use a custom pattern by combining and blending the images in a certain way:

```
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins // needed for using the type-safe filter interface

// ...

let patternImage = UIImage(named: "<image_name>")!
var patternInput = CIImage(cgImage: patternImage.cgImage!)

// potentially scale the pattern image
patternInput = patternInput.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))

let codeFilter = CIFilter.aztecCodeGenerator()
codeFilter.message = "<message>".data(using: .utf8)!
var codeImage = codeFilter.outputImage!

// invert code so the actual code part is white
let colorInvertFilter = CIFilter.colorInvert()
colorInvertFilter.inputImage = codeImage
codeImage = colorInvertFilter.outputImage!

// potentially scale the barcode (using nearest sampling to retain sharp edges)
codeImage = codeImage.samplingNearest().transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 50, y: 50))

let blendFilter = CIFilter.blendWithMask()
blendFilter.inputImage = patternInput
// using white color as background here, but can be any (or transparent when alpha = 0)
blendFilter.backgroundImage = CIImage(color: CIColor.white).cropped(to: codeImage.extent)
blendFilter.maskImage = codeImage

let output = blendFilter.outputImage!
```

Objective-C version:

```
// the image containing the pattern you want to show over the aztec code
CIImage *patternImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];

// potentially scale the pattern image, if necessary
patternImage = [patternImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)];

// generate aztec code image
CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAztecCodeGenerator"];
[qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
CIImage *codeImage = qrFilter.outputImage;

// invert code so the actual code part is white (used for masking below)
codeImage = [codeImage imageByApplyingFilter: @"CIColorInvert"];

// potentially scale the aztec code (using nearest sampling to retain sharp edges)
codeImage = [[codeImage imageBySamplingNearest] imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(50, 50)];

// the background color for your aztec code; basically a solid color image of the same size of the code
CIImage *background = [[CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor whiteColor]] imageByCroppingToRect:codeImage.extent];

//
CIFilter *blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
[blendFilter setValue:patternImage forKey:@"inputImage"]; // the pattern image is in the foreground
[blendFilter setValue:background forKey:@"backgroundImage"]; // solid color in the aztec code, but could be any color or image
[blendFilter setValue:codeImage forKey:@"maskImage"]; // use the aztec code as a mask for the pattern image over the background

CIImage *output = blendFilter.outputImage
```

Note that the numbers in the two scaling steps depend on how large you want to display the code and how the pattern image should be scaled above the code.

Comment: Brilliant is this possible in Objective C?

Comment: Yes, definitely. All those APIs are also available in Objective-C.

Comment: Brilliant I have this so far:

     CIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData].CIImage;
      [colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
            
            
            CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];

            CIImage* outputx = colorFilter.outputImage;
            [colorFilter setValue:outputx forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
            [colorFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputMaskImageKey];
            [colorFilter setValue:outputx forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];

Comment: I think what i'm missing is the cropped to section from your line here: 

blendFilter.backgroundImage = CIImage(color: CIColor.white).cropped(to: codeImage.extent)

Do you know the Objc equivilent?

Comment: That should be `blendFilter.backgroundImage = [[CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor blackColor]] imageByCroppingToRect:codeImage.extent]`.

Comment: Thanks I tried something like that already but it has the following issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIdq1.png

Comment: Ah sorry, then `CIImage* background = [[CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor blackColor]] imageByCroppingToRect:codeImage.extent]; [blendFilter setValue: background forKey: @"backgroundImage"];`

Comment: No need to apologies you're helping me and i'm very grateful

That allows me to run it but when I select an image it crashes below is my code and the console error, any idea?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTgUI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FRgk.png

Comment: Hmm, two things: Instead of the `CIFalseColor` you can just use `CIColorInvert` to flip the colors of the barcode image. Also, the inputs of the blend filter are wrong. The pattern image should be foreground (`inputImage`), the solid color should be background (`backgroundImage`) and the inverted barcode image should be used as mask (`maskImage`).

Comment: Thanks i've now done that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSYCO.png but doesn't seem to be working still or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: I added an Objective-C version to my answer. ☝️

Comment: You're amazing i've really struggled to find documentation surrounding this and the only ones I could find were in swift! You're sure as star! i've marked your answer as the answer :) I've plussed 1 too but as my rep is less than 15 it doesn't show but is recorded :)

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help 